# How to multiply row values in two columns of a dataframe if the result per row is less than x?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to multiply two independent columns with each other until their product is bigger than x.

```
d = {
    'name': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'i1': [1,2,3,5,1],
    'i2': [2,2,2,6,8],
    'result': [2,4,6,30,8]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

  name  i1  i2  result
0    A   1   2       2
1    B   2   2       4
2    C   3   2       6
3    D   5   6      30
4    E   1   8       8
```

I want the loop being repeated as long as the result is less than x.

```
for _index, row in df.iterrows():
    while row['result'] < 10:
        row['i1'] = row['i1'] * 2
        row['i2'] = row['i2'] * 2
        row['result'] = row['i1'] * row['i2']
    else:
        pass
```

I don't receive any error, but the df stays untouched. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what's the best way to solve this?

**First solution**

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    while df.loc[index, 'result'] < 10:
        df.loc[index, 'i1'] = df.loc[index, 'i1'] * 2
        df.loc[index, 'i2'] = df.loc[index, 'i2'] * 2
        df.loc[index, 'result'] = df.loc[index, 'i1'] * df.loc[index, 'i2']
    else:
        pass

  name  i1  i2  result
0    A   4   8      32
1    B   4   4      16
2    C   6   4      24
3    D   5   6      30
4    E   2  16      32
```

**New problem**

The steps into the direction of my target are too huge. A better solution might be to store the original values per row and add them too the current values within the loop (I need them to stay Integers). This is what I tried:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    i1 = df.loc[index, 'i1']
    i2 = df.loc[index, 'i2']

    while df.loc[index, 'result'] < 10:
        df.loc[index, 'i1'] = df.loc[index, 'i1'] + i1
        df.loc[index, 'i2'] = df.loc[index, 'i2'] + i2
        df.loc[index, 'result'] = df.loc[index, 'i1'] * df.loc[index, 'i2']
    else:
        pass
```

But running the loop never ends and I have to break it with CTRL-C.

Comment: The `row` in `iterrows` is not attached to the DataFrame so updating it will not affect the dataframe. If you're updating the dataframe you'll need to use `df.loc[_index, 'i1'] = `. Also be careful with this what happens if either `i1` or `i2` are 0 or one of them is a fraction or both are 1? Lots of cases where you'll never meet the termination condition.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you call this *multiplying two columns until x* when in fact you multiply the two columns once, and then keep doubling the result.

Comment: It's very confusing that you write *want to multiply two independent columns with each other until their product is bigger than x*. The code you supplied doubles the columns until their product is bigger than x. This is different from multiplying columns with each other until their product is bigger than x. Can you please clarify what you're really trying to do?

Comment: Basically ``df['result']`` is my profit and ``i1`` and ``i2`` are numerator and denominator of a fraction. I would like to raise those until I hit my target profit without changing the quotient of the fraction. Multiplying them by 2 is just an example for the required function in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to double the values of `i1` and `i2` or just quadruple the result.

This solution is for the case if you just want to quadruple the result.

```py
def quadruple_till_bt_10(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return pd.NA
    while(x<10):
        x *= 4
    return x

df = df.assign(result=df.i1*df.i2)
df.result = df.result.apply(quadruple_till_bt_10)
```

Rather than getting stuck in an infinite loop, it returns `NA` when the product is 0 or negative.

Comment: For the example I just want to double the values. But actually I would like to multiply those numbers with any kind of factor until I hit my target result. Since both numbers are numerator and denominator of a fraction ``from fraction import Fraction`` and ``Fraction('decimalnumber').numerator``, ``Fraction('decimalnumber').denominator`` I need to keep the ratio.